# How to achieve a curve like the one here?

Tags: html, css

i'm creating a new website and im looking to recreate the curved corner of the SAVE 25% banner. http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/

Does anyone know how i would do this with css or html?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use the image as a `background-image`, and apply `border-radius` on the element

```
div
{
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    width:350px;height:150px;
    border-radius:5px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mdNCm/1/

---

You can use [border-radius.com](http://border-radius.com/) to generate cross-browser  CSS

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of border-radius, so went to Google and found this: http://border-radius.com/

Comment: @PedroLamarão I use that site every time I create cross-browser rounded borders!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using [border-radius](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp).

**CSS:**

```
div.rounded{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rounded">This text is in a rounded border!</div>
```

Comment: It should be noted that not all browsers support this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Answer (score 1):

This is a css3 feature and not yet fully supported of all browsers. Read further about this tag:

```
border-radius: 25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with
border-radius: 5px;

If you want a cornered border please use this.
Border-radius.com
Which gives you the code.

Note: border-radius don't work with some browsers such as ie

Alternatively you can use some image as background in css.